# Haskell why is System.Random in a monad

Tags: haskell, random, monads

I want to use a random number generator. After doing research I found out, that System.Random is the only way to do that (except programming a RNG yourself). Can someone please tell me what the difference is between the RNGs from this class? I have the following simple structure:

```
data Tree = Leaf
            | Function Tree Tree
            | Lambda Tree
            deriving (Show)
```

When I use mkStdGen to build a random tree, that tree will have the type

```
baum :: Int -> Tree
```

And I can't let the console show me the tree (If I have a random generated tree called a and if I type a in the console I get an error).
When I use getStdGen, that tree will have the type

```
baum :: IO Tree
```

And I can let the console show me my tree (If I have a random generated tree called a and if I type a in the console it displays the tree).

So what is the difference between those two RNGs and are both giving me back a tree in a Monad? (Why is the mk version giving back: Int -> Tree?)

Because of data protection reason I can't post my code here.
The type signature of my function is build :: RandomGen g => Int -> Int -> Int -> Int -> g -> Tree. All I want to do is to generate my tree randomly with some parameters. I need this for a university project. I don't know which RNG is the best to choose and if it is inevitable that I don't get only a Tree back.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean?   `StdGen` is a type provided by the `System.Random` module and is not a monad.  You can construct `StdGen`s without any monad and use those (via `next`) also with no monad.  Are you wondering why getting a uniquely seeded generator requires IO?

Comment: A random number generator is just a `State` monad in disguise; (part of) the return value of one call to the RNG is passed as an argument to the next call to ensure that a different PRN can be returned each time.

Comment: I guess I got it wrong. I thought I only can use the RNG with giving mw back a monad. So what's the difference  between the mentioned uniquely seed generator and the StdGen?

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson I edited my question. Would you please have a look at it?

Comment: Your words reveal some misunderstandings that make this question answerable so I'll vote to re-open. I'll comment for now (I'm hoping someone else answers or I will later): The two RNGs are the same (both are RNGs of type `StdGen`). In one case you provide an explicit seed (or, leave it to someone else to provide, hence the `Int` argument) while in the other you expect some IO action to give you the seed.  I think you misunderstand the values - `IO Tree` is not a tree but an operation that returns a tree.  `Int -> Tree` is a function from Ints to Trees (returns a tree computed from the Int).

Comment: OK, I voted to re-open. I suggest you also include your code (both versions of `baum`) since your questions center on it.  Others could invent a similar function but that's not preferable.